# Can you say "Alone <object>"?

Tags: objects

can you say for example:

Alone Potato?

I want to say that a potato is alone, like "look at that alone potato".

I think lonely Potato is better right?
But can you say alone potato also? Or is this sounding weird?

DeepL is translating it right to german, but google translator not, so im asking here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the 'right translation' that DeepL gives you? Does it use '_einsam_' (lonely) or '_allein_' (alone)? These words have different meanings in English as in German.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alone) states clearly: 'Alone ...
_Alone_ is an adjective and an adverb meaning that no other person is with you. When we use _alone_ as an adjective, it never comes before the noun (ie it is a predicative adjective)....' We might speak of a 'lone tree' or a 'solitary example', but not an 'alone tree/example'. I'm not sure I'd ever use a 'lone potato', though it's not ungrammatical.

Comment: Try using "solitary".

Comment: "Potato's all alone" or "Lonesome potato" if you're looking for something literary or descriptive for your avatar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alone* is a contraction of [*all-ane*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/alone) ‘all one’ and may only appear after the noun modified, either following the noun/pronoun or in the predicate. Its cognates in German (*allein*) and Dutch (*alleen*) function the same way, though in these two languages, unlike in English, they may appear before a definite or indefinite article as English uses *only*. I'm not sure, however, why that should influence your word choice in English.

> Now she was [*alone*](https://books.google.de/books?id=zryCBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22was+alone+even%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9u_uRtKXaAhVsDJoKHe0UBvI4HhDoAQhZMAk), even the deck hand had disappeared.
>
> The President [*alone*](https://books.google.de/books?id=2ULv4NzlAFEC&pg=PA23&dq=%22he+alone+can%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiktfqItaXaAhUFEpoKHQhuDzQQ6AEIOzAE) can declare that circumstances are exceptional ... and he *alone* can determine that the situation is back to normal.
>
> In her impressive study of black and white women in plantation households, Elizabeth Fox-Genovese states that “a woman [*alone*](https://books.google.de/books?id=CfTQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&dq=%22a+woman+alone+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZq5qhtqXaAhXJXCwKHWYRDrcQ6AEILzAC) on the public thoroughfares was a woman at risk.”
>
> The fiber and the nutrients in the potato [*alone*](https://superfoodsrx.com/healthyliving/potatoes-nutrition/) should differentiate it from the other “high carb” foods.

*Lone*, however, may appear in the normal attributive position before a noun, but cannot be used as a predicate adjective as *alone* can be:

> It seems the [*lone*](https://www.newsday.com/entertainment/movies/w-a-prime-candidate-for-oliver-stone-1.886440) president who simultaneously occupied the big screen and the Oval Office was John F. Kennedy: "PT 109," released five months before the 1963 assassination, starred Cliff Robertson and concerned the young JFK as war hero...
>
> Life was indeed hard, but Mrs. Ullmann never realized … that it was harder still for a [*lone*](https://books.google.de/books?id=sOwcwe-OW-wC&pg=PA190&dq=%22a+lone+woman+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW4_7jtqXaAhXpCpoKHb1JD_AQ6AEINzAD) woman on the bleak prairie striving to wrest a livelihood from the stubborn hard soil.
>
> She could have sworn she'd peeled enough potatoes to feed an army. Instead, the [*lone*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ovNvBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&dq=%22the+lone+potato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihocz4uqXaAhXHjiwKHWPFAVkQ6AEINjAD) potato in the pan stared back at her.

This woman's lone potato is the one you're looking for unless you want to personify a root vegetable so that it feels alone, but even that sentient tuber can't be **an alone potato*.

Comment: Nice answer! So, just to be sure: an app called "Alone Potato" should be renamed? Because it's sounding just wrong?

Comment: @JietzoRawit If you got rid of all the apps with odd/wrong names, the app-stores would be nigh-on empty:-) As far as "correct English" is concerned, "_Lone Potato_" or "_A Lone Potato_" would be better. Whether it's a _good_ title depends on what the app does...

Comment: @JietzoRawit: it's not a possible construction in English. Be aware, however, there is a band called "Lone Potato," so that might not be an option either.